# Inconsistent error when using ADODB in VBA with parameters for RecordSet Open

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

This line of code:

```
rs.Open SQLStr, conn, adOpenStatic
```

is proving somewhat volatile - sometimes it runs with no problem, and sometimes it throws the error:

> Variable not defined.

It appears to be the `adOpenStatic` causing problems. I'm trying to avoid referencing the ADODB library as it would then require all of my users to reference this library. If it didn't work full stop then fine but my frustration stems from the fact that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Just wondered if anyone had come across this before and had a solution?

Comment: Why would you late bind this? "trying to avoid referencing the ADODB library as it would then require all of my users to reference this library" doesn't make any sense - if they don't have the library installed, `CreateObject` is going to throw anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with external libriary in `late-binding mode` you can not work with constants like `adOpenStatic`. Use `3` istead (just three) wich is numeric representation of `adOpenStatic`.

Other parameters and theirs numeric repesentations you can find [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_rs_open.asp#CursorTypeEnum)